# SQLite "SQL Error or missing database" Objective-C

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, database, sqlite

I'm currently getting an error when trying to insert data into my database.

```
#import "ReminderDB.h"

@implementation ReminderDB

@synthesize db = _db;

-(id)init{
    _db = [self openDB];
    [self createTable:@"Reminders" withField1:@"Title" withField2:@"Who" withField3:@"Quantity"];
    return self;
}

-(NSString *) filepath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"reminders.sqlite"];
}

- (sqlite3*)openDB {
    if (_db == NULL) {
        int rc;

        if ((rc = sqlite3_open([[self filepath] UTF8String], &(_db))) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"%s error (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, rc);
            _db = NULL;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"db opened");
        }
    }
    return _db;
}
-(void)createTable: (NSString *) tableName
        withField1: (NSString *) field1
        withField2: (NSString *) field2
        withField3: (NSString *) field3
{
    char *err;
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' ('%@' TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT);", tableName, field1, field2, field3];
    if(sqlite3_exec(_db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(_db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not create table");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Table Created");
    }
}
-(void)addReminder:(NSString*)title
               who:(NSString*)who
          quantity:(NSString*)quantity{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Reminders ('Title', 'Who', 'Quantity') VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@')", title, who, quantity];
    char *err;
    int rc;
    if((rc = sqlite3_exec(_db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err)) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"%s error (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, rc);
        sqlite3_close(_db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not update table");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Table Update Successful");
    }
}

@end
```

This code successfully opens the database and creates the table. However when I call `addReminder:who:quantity` the table will not update and the error I am getting is an `SQL Error or Missing Database` error. Which doesn't make sense to me because I know the table is created and exists.

**EDIT**
I have updated my `addReminder:who:quantity:` to use binds instead of exec's. I have also taken out the close calls. I am now getting an error when calling prepare.

```
-(void)addReminder:(NSString*)title
           who:(NSString*)who
      quantity:(NSString*)quantity{

    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO Reminders ('Title', 'Who', 'Quantity') VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Bind the parameters (note that these use a 1-based index, not 0).
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [who UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [quantity UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSLog(@"Binding successful");
    }
    int returnCode = sqlite3_step(statement);
    if (returnCode != SQLITE_DONE) {
        // error handling...
        NSLog(@"An error occoured (%d)", returnCode);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Table Updated");
    }
}
```

I know the problem is in the prepare call because I am not getting "Binding successful" in my log.

Comment: Do you call `[self openDB]` before `[self addReminder:::]`?

Comment: Do you call your `openDB` method before calling `addReminder:who:quantity:`? And why is your insert being done via `sqlite3_exec` and why do you build your query with `stringWithFormat`?

Comment: The code is pretty asymmetric. You have a method to open the database but every operation closes the database.  1) Leave it open all the time, 2) have the methods which do things, open the database if necessary (i.e. keep state about if the database is open; which is easy given you have a pointer which can be `NULL` if it's closed). Not to mention the SQL injection attacks alluded to by @rmaddy.

Comment: @trojanfoe @rmaddy I followed the tutorial found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3eMdrjPYkM. which is why I've used `sqlite3_exec` and `stringWithFormat`. If that is incorrect then what is the better way to do it?  `openDB` and `createTable:field1:field2:field3:` are both called before `addReminder`. If you see I am not closing the database in the methods if they run successfully. I am only closing the database if the opens or execs to not succeed.

Comment: You need to use bind variables and semantics of these methods is a mess.  Simply return `BOOL` and leave the decision about closing the database to calling code.  Leave the database open until the app goes into the background and open it again when the app comes back into the foreground.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am very new to SQL and have obtained all my information from youtube.com/watch?v=C3eMdrjPYkM where she has used formatStrings to make commands. I will take out the closing calls and I will look into bind variables. However I know in this case that closing the database is not the problem. I know now that I should take those out, but they are never being called. The error is being thrown when I try to execute the command to insert data into the table. I understand I am not doing it the best way, but theoretically this should still work. In the tutorial it runs successfully.

Comment: Any tutorial that uses `stringWithFormat` to build queries or uses `sqlite_exec` to do `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements is a bad tutorial. Find a better one.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated the `addReminder:who:quantity` to use binds and step instead of stringWithFormat and exec. I am now having problems with the prepare call.

Comment: @Rob so are you saying I should put `NSLog(@"%s SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_db), sqlite3_errcode(_db));` immediately after the prepare call so the error message doesn't change after I call step?

Comment: @Rob Okay I have added it, the error is now `SQL error 'table Reminders has no column named Who'` However I clearly have made a 'Who' column. I will try rewriting my createTable: method using binds, maybe that will fix it.

Comment: @ddresner8 BTW, you cannot use `sqlite3_bind` with `CREATE TABLE` statement, so don't even bother trying that. But it's critical to do that with `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. I don't see anything in the provided code snippet that would produce a warning that says "SQL Error or Missing Database". Have you identified where that's being produced?
2. If you close the database anywhere, don't forget to set `_db` to `NULL`. You might have a close method that looks like:

   ```
   - (int)closeDB {
       if (_db) {
           int rc = sqlite3_close(_db);
           _db = NULL;
           return rc;
       }
       return SQLITE_OK;
   }
   ```

   Having said that, you generally don't open and close databases while an app is running, so this might not be critical. But if you are closing it anywhere, make sure to `NULL` the pointer, too. Otherwise your `openDB` method won't work properly if you try to reopen the database.
3. In your `addReminder` method, make sure to log `sqlite3_errmsg`:

   ```
   -(void)addReminder:(NSString*)title
                  who:(NSString*)who
             quantity:(NSString*)quantity {

       const char *sql = "INSERT INTO Reminders ('Title', 'Who', 'Quantity') VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
       sqlite3_stmt *statement;
       int returnCode;

       if ((returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK) {
           // Bind the parameters (note that these use a 1-based index, not 0).
           sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [who UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [quantity UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           NSLog(@"Binding successful");
       } else {
           NSLog(@"Prepare failed: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(_db), (long) returnCode);
           return;
       }

       returnCode = sqlite3_step(statement);
       if (returnCode != SQLITE_DONE) {
           // error handling...
           NSLog(@"An error occurred: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(_db), (long)returnCode);
       }
       else{
           NSLog(@"Table Updated");
       }

       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   }
   ```

   Note, don't forget to call `sqlite3_finalize` whenever you call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` or else you'll leak memory.
4. As an aside, your `CREATE TABLE` call is creating `Quantity` as a `TEXT` column. You might want to create that as `INTEGER` if it's an integer value, or `REAL` if it's a floating point value.

   When you bind values for the `Quantity` value, you might want to use the type-appropriate bind call, e.g.

   ```
   sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, [quantity intValue]);
   ```

   Clearly, though, your `createTable` method seems to be hard coded to create a table with three `TEXT` columns, so you might want to refactor that, too (though SQLite ignores the column definition when inserting values, so this isn't absolutely critical).

   But, by storing numeric data types, it means that when you sort by `Quantity` column or do arithmetic calculations, SQLite will handle this properly. Actually, SQLite is pretty flexible in terms of converting string values to numeric values in many cases, so this isn't critical, but I think it's still appropriate to store numeric values as numbers, rather than strings.

   Note, the above point is completely unrelated to your problem at hand, but it does reflect best practice.
5. You say that your `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement is producing an error that says:

   > table Reminders has no column named Who

   Your create statement only creates the table if it doesn't exist. So if you accidentally created it earlier using different columns, then "Who" might not be found, because it won't recreate a table that already exists.

   Open the database from the simulator/device (not from the project folder, if you have one there) using your Mac OS X database tool of choice (or the `sqlite3` command line program, if you don't have a nice database tool) and take a look at the table and make sure what the column names are. When dealing with the simulator, the precise location of this folder depends upon what version of Xcode you're using. In Xcode 5, it's in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` and then navigate to the appropriate iOS version and application, and look in the appropriate `Documents` subfolder. In Xcode 6 it's located in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` (and you have to figure out which cryptic folder the app is in, often simplified if you sort this folder by "date"). And, if you're not seeing `~/Library`, make sure to unhide the `Library` folder, easily shown by using the command `chflags nohidden ~/Library` from the `Terminal` command line.

   Or just delete the app from the simulator/device and start over, letting it recreate the database again, so you know you're not dealing with an old, out-of-date database.
6. While I encourage you to finish this up using the SQLite C API (it's a good learning experience), I must say that you might want to investigate [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which is an Objective-C wrapper around the SQLite C API. I wouldn't do that right now (you have too many moving parts and I don't want to confuse the situation further), but after you address your immediate challenges, it's worth considering.